# QT/C++ : Resizing customized layout with mainwindow

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt, working on some office task(for confidentiality labels are hidden).

**Requirement:** As per the requirement the layout is customized, I have to stick to the same layout(PFA). Infact, one more similar layout will be there below this in the same mainwindow.

[image]

**Question:** How do I retain the same layout and make it the view resizable?

I have gone through Qt docs and various Stack Overflow answers & found out applying a layout makes the widgets resizable. But I am unable to achieve this customize layout with existing Layouts provided by Qt. How do I achieve this?

QSizePolicy Snapshot:
[image]

Mainwindow.ui:
[image]

Comment: if you use qt designer select the mainwindow widget and select a type of layout from top toolbar (beside edit tab order button)that you want to set on view.

Comment: You mean resizing the single widgets inside the the window or have them scale accordinly to the size of the containing window? Could you please explain a little more what you want to achieve? Could you post your .ui file?

Comment: @SajadHosseini, Thank you!. But as I mentioned, existing layouts not giving me the layout I am looking for(it should be exactly as attached in the question). Grid, Vertical, Horizontal, Form, not able to achieve this with any of these layouts.

Comment: @JackLilhammers, I meant re scaling of all the widgets, as I resize the main window.

Comment: if you have added a layout for centeralWidget and your problem is resizing of content, you maybe need to change minimum size or sizePolicy https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#PolicyFlag-enum

Comment: for sizePolicy you can select all widget's and change sizePolicy in the property editor

Comment: I went through the qt docs, but unable to find where I can make, QSizePolicy::Minimum GrowFlag. Please refer the attachment, I added now.